# Errors posting a form from a html/javascript file hosting AWS Cloudfront & S3 over HTTPS

Tags: post, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have static content for a website (HTML and JavaScript) hosted in an AWS S3 bucket behind an AWS Cloudfront distribution using HTTPS.

I've Googled and read a lot about the problem but not found an answer to suit my simple circumstance (no Facebook, just a simple contact form).

The HTML includes a contact form with all the usual stuff.

The JavaScript looks like this.

```
 $('form#contactForm button.submit').click(function() {

      $('#image-loader').fadeIn();

      var contactName = $('#contactForm #contactName').val();
      var contactEmail = $('#contactForm #contactEmail').val();
      var contactSubject = $('#contactForm #contactSubject').val();
      var contactMessage = $('#contactForm #contactMessage').val();

      var data = 'contactName=' + contactName + '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail +
               '&contactSubject=' + contactSubject + '&contactMessage=' + contactMessage;

      $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: "https://contact.website.com/inc/sendEmail.php",
          data: data,
          success: function(msg) {

            // Message was sent
            if (msg == 'OK') {
                                window.location.replace("https://www.website.com/response.html");

            }
            // There was an error
            else {
               $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
               $('#message-warning').html(msg);
                 $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
            }

          }

      });
```

See how the post goes to a subdomain with a different domain / A record from the Cloudfront distribution, but it is also via HTTPS.

The error thrown by Cloudfront (I believe - but why would the post go to Cloudfront when it doesn't use the distribution domain???) is:

```
<html>
<head><title>405 Method Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<h1>405 Method Not Allowed</h1>
<ul>
<li>Code: MethodNotAllowed</li>
<li>Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</li>
<li>Method: POST</li>
<li>ResourceType: OBJECT</li>
<li>RequestId: E2BD58A9310500B7</li>
<li>HostId: VC3CF0HmNQU+ZsVJ2XVu+xBlExVZje9gKZNGVRYnPoZ3wnhTTtQ2L6PBlP6ciTMUM9qp377jhgk=</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also made these changes to AWS Cloudfront to enable POST method:

[Cloudfront settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVPrM.png)

I've also made these changes to AWS S3 Bitbucket to enable POST via CORS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

If you say it can't be done, please explain why and the best alternative.

Thank you.

regards,
Andrew.

Comment: The HTTP POST request now goes via AWS API Gateway to a Lambda function that sends the contact data by email. No more back-end server on a different domain. But still the same 405 error, even though I receive the email... It remains a negative user experience to get an error when it worked...

Comment: It looks like the HTTP POST is duplicated, once to the rest API (/rest/contact/) and once to root (/). I'm not sure how to stop this behaviour at present. Anyone any thoughts?? Thanks, Andrew.